# show that the group of rational numbers under addition can not be written as direct sum of two non trivial subgroups

Tags: group-theory

show that the group of rational numbers  under addition can not be written as direct sum of two non trivial subgroups. ifound this as an unsolved exercice in a book i cannot understand how to do it please someone help

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Use that for all $x,y\in \mathbb{Q}$ there are such $m,n\in \mathbb{Z}$ that $mx=ny$.